# How can I grab the XML data using Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

Google sheet has a function `importxml()` to grab data from a webpage, I want to grab the table from https://rss.weather.gov.hk/rss/CurrentWeather.xml, it is an XML with XSL when I view the page source, I find the `&lt;td&gt;` tag, I try to input

```
=IMPORTXML("https://rss.weather.gov.hk/rss/CurrentWeather.xml", "//td")
```

in the cell but it returns `#N/A`, what is the syntax error I made? Or the content format not acceptable to Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTXML(
 "https://rss.weather.gov.hk/rss/CurrentWeather.xml", "//*"), 21, 1), 
 CHAR(10))), "(.*) \d+ degrees ;"), TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTXML(
 "https://rss.weather.gov.hk/rss/CurrentWeather.xml", "//*"), 21, 1), 
 CHAR(10)))), IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTXML(
 "https://rss.weather.gov.hk/rss/CurrentWeather.xml", "//*"), 21, 1), 
 CHAR(10))), "\d+ degrees ;"))})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: How to count the index is 21 and is it possible to extract the line 6 to 32 from the result?

Comment: @Kelvin try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTXML(
 "https://rss.weather.gov.hk/rss/CurrentWeather.xml", "//*"), 21, 1), 
 CHAR(10))), "(.*) \d+ degrees ;")), IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTXML(
 "https://rss.weather.gov.hk/rss/CurrentWeather.xml", "//*"), 21, 1), 
 CHAR(10))), "\d+ degrees ;"))}, "where Col1 is not null", 0))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6dPl.png

Comment: @Kelvin 21 because if you paste this in 1st row, the 21st is one you need - `=IMPORTXML( "https://rss.weather.gov.hk/rss/CurrentWeather.xml", "//*")`

Comment: very nice, I can extract the data with location and number but still including the first 3 lines. These first 3 lines are not the location, but I can put formula  =query(A4:B) in another cell, any better suggestion?

Comment: you can wrap it all in query and offset it by 3 - `=QUERY(fxhere, "offset 3", 0)`